# Looking to speed up Swf to Jpg to PDF Conversion? Taking Ideas (no code)

Tags: php, flash, pdf

Trying to find an efficient way to convert Graphs 50 of them to Images. 
Then take those images and insert them into a PDF that is built on the server.

Problem is this process takes so long on our server as the serve must open each of the 50 graphs then take a snapshot of each one to turn them into images. Then the server take the users data and formulate a PDF that also contains these images.

Any solutions? Current process takes around 10 minutes for our clients and sometimes hangs up during conversion.

We currently use Fusion Charts as our Charting/Graph program.
PHP for our coding and conversion into PDF.

This question is probably vague or worded horribly, but I am not sure where else to go for solutions and this community is extremely helpful.